# рантайм ошибка при выполнении objc функции в swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, функции

В моей коде мне нужно отложить запуск функции. В коде я реализовал это так

```
 perform(#selector(loadDeclarationDateIssue(for:)), with: self.loadingIndex, afterDelay: 1)

 @objc func loadDeclarationDateIssue(for declarant: Int) {
    guard loadingIndex < (declarationInfo?.items.count)! else {return}
    declarationInfoController.fetchDeclarationDetails(with: (declarationInfo?.items[declarant].id)!) { (declarationInfoElement) in
 ....
```

несмотря на то, что loadingIndex это обычный Int, который увеличивается в каждым циклом начиная с нуля на единицу - я сталкиваюсь с рантайм ошибкой, а именно при значении self.loadingIndex и соответственно declarant как параметра функции равном 1, в дебаггере указано: declarant  Int -4701082813037527317. Как и почему 1 превратилась в -4701082813037527317???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform больше objectiveC функция. Точной причины не знаю почему так происходит. Но более "свифтовое" решение через Dispatch.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        //your code
    }
```

Так же можно написать свой метод для передачи параметров.

```
func runMethodAfter (_ timeInSecond: Double, withParams params: Int) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + timeInSecond) {
        print(params)
    }
}
```

И реализовать его в коде.

```
runMethodAfter(1, withParams: loadingIndex)
```